# How to controlls icons with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, icons

I'm stuck at this problem i want to controll my font awesome icons hover and click with javascript, i want to show another icon when user hover to icon and when user leave the icon previous icon comes back. when user click the icon new icon comes and when user leave the mouse previous icon not comes back and when user again click the icon previous icon come back.

Here is my Html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/471cefd7e0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
                           <span class="select-me">
                            <i class="far fa-heart wishlist-item"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-heart wishlist-item2"></i>
                          </span>
                           <span class="select-me">
                            <i class="far fa-heart wishlist-item"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-heart wishlist-item2"></i>
                          </span>
                           <span class="select-me">
                            <i class="far fa-heart wishlist-item"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-heart wishlist-item2"></i>
                          </span>



  </body>
</html>
```

Css Code:

```
.wishlist-item {
            color: red;
            font-size: 2.5rem;
         }
.select-me .wishlist-item2 {
            display: none;
            color: red;
            font-size: 2.5rem;
          }
```

Js code:

```
    var checkIt = true;
var node = document.querySelectorAll('.wishlist-item')
var node2 = document.querySelectorAll('.wishlist-item2')
var wishlistItems =  Array.prototype.slice.call(node);
var wishlistItems2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(node2);
for(var i = 0; i < wishlistItems.length; i++) {

wishlistItems[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){

    this.style.display = "none"
    wishlistItems2[( wishlistItems.indexOf( this ) )].style.display = "block"
})
}
for(var i = 0; i < wishlistItems2.length; i++) {

    wishlistItems2[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){

    if (checkIt === true){
        this.style.display = "none"
        wishlistItems[( wishlistItems2.indexOf( this ) )].style.display = "block";

    }


})
}
for (var i = 0; i < wishlistItems2.length; i++) {
    wishlistItems2[i].addEventListener('click', function(){



        this.style.display = "block";
        wishlistItems[( wishlistItems2.indexOf( this ) )].style.display = "none";
        checkIt = false;


    })
}
```

Link for jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/se9ym43r/)

Comment: Hello anyone here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is the way you are identifying what you are mousing over. You're selecting the span element, but then trying to change something in the i element, which is a child. Change your script to that below and it will work. Also, if you don't want the icons to move when they're hovered over, add float: left; to both css classes. (Also, I assume you're calling the CSS and JS files from your HTML file.)

```
var checkIt = true
var select = document.querySelectorAll('.select-me')
var wishlistItems = document.querySelectorAll('.wishlist-item')
var wishlistItems2 = document.querySelectorAll('.wishlist-item2')
for(var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
    var add = i
select[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){

    this.children[0].style.display = "none";
    this.children[1].style.display = "block"
    console.log("mouseenter");
})
}
for(var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {

select[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){

    if(checkIt === true) {
        this.children[0].style.display = "block"
        this.children[1].style.display = "none";
    }
console.log("mouse leave");
})
}

for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
select[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(checkIt === true) {
    checkIt = false;
    }
    else {
        checkIt = true;
    }
    console.log("mouseclick");

    })
}
```

Comment: You might want to delete all the console.logs. Also, the way this is written the click event will affect the behaviour of all of the icons. To change that you can either add a class to each icon and modify it, or have three click variables related to the three icons.

Comment: I want handle it dynamically suppose if i have 100 icons i modify all classes of 100 icons ?

Comment: That would be the way I would do it. Give each icon a class unchecked, and on a click event change that class to checked using this.children[]. Then, base the behaviour of hover-over on which class is there.

Comment: Also, if this answer was useful, please accept it so the question shows as answered.